# Combining UINavigationController with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iOS app which asks the user to either login or signup before using the functionality. The flow is;
The app displays a screen with 2 buttons 1) Login 2) Signup
Upon clicking either button the app navigates the user to different view controllers using UiNavigationController.
Upon successful login the user is directed towards a home view controller which displays a tab bar on the bottom of the view and a UiNavigationController's top bar on the top of the view.

To implement this, I have set the UINavigationViewController as the root view controller in the AppDelegate file.

As soon as the user is authenticated, I push the tab bar controller on the UiNavigationController using the following code.

```
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [firstViewController setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"1st" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1st.png"] tag:101]];

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [secondViewController setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"2nd" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2nd.png"] tag:102]];

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [thirdViewController setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"3rd" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3rd.png"] tag:104]];


    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController,thirdViewController, nil]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

Is this the right approach?
Someone just said that the using tab bar controller as root view controller will be a better approach.
How can I just set the tab bar controller as root view controller as I dont want to show the tab bar on login/signup screens....

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a protocol, so you can communicate between your login `UIViewController` and your `AppDelegate`. Once the login has been done, you can change the `rootViewController`. You can also get a reference to the AppDelegate, by doing something like:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Although I prefer to use protocols to communicate between different objects.